# VirtualBox SDK JAVA

Tags: java, sdk, virtualbox

Trying to get the VirtualBox SDK to work with Java for Windows. The documentation says that, for Windows, you need to use 'vboxjmscom.jar' which doesn't exist in the SDK. I try to use the 'vboxjxpcom.jar' and can import it with no problems, but when I try to run a simple test script I run into this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.virtualbox_5_0.VBoxException: vbox.home Java property must be defined to use XPCOM bridge
at org.virtualbox_5_0.VirtualBoxManager.createInstance(VirtualBoxManager.java:108)
at TestVBox.main(TestVBox.java:220)
```

I added the arguments from the documentation to the Jacob folder 'c:\jacob\jacob.jar -Djava.library.path=c:\jacob MyProgram' and corrected the path to where I've stored it. I then instead get the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class c:\jacob\jacob.jar
```

Anyone successfully used the VirtualBox SDK on Windows before? I'm not sure what to do and there's very little help to find.

Comment: See https://github.com/enexusde/vboxjws/wiki/Code-Examples